# Adding event handler to dynamically added span elements

Tags: jquery

I want to bind a click even to the dynamically added span elements to a node on my page.
I wrote the bind event for a single static element and it works fine -

```
function clickSpan(domNode){
   $(domNode).find("span").bind("click", function(){
      alert("span clicked");
   });
}
```

I tried writing the same for dynamically added elements and changed the "bind" to the "on" method. Somehow this doesn't work for the dynamically added span elements. How do i make the dynamically added span elements to respond to clicks?

Comment: [Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this code:

```
$('#parent_selector').on('click', 'span', function(){
    alert("here");
});
```